# kdb q - reading binary file into table

Tags: kdb

I got a binary file which looks something like this

`` read0 hsym`$binaryfile ``

```
("   I D ^ I D 2    
 ";" 1 0 0 ^ 1 0   
 ";" 2 0 0 ^ 2 0 ...
```

In python I can read the binary file into a pandas dataframe like so

```
from io import BytesIO
with open(binaryfile, "rb") as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(f.read().decode("UTF-16").encode("UTF-8")), encoding = "utf-8", delimiter="^")
```

but instead of saving this dataframe down to a csv I would like to load it into a q table by reading from the file directly.

I have tried the `0:` operator by first concatenating the list of strings above and then using
`(types; delimiter[;allowEmbeddedLineReturns]) 0: string`,

i.e.
`` ("SS";" ^ ";enlist"|") 0: "|" sv read0 hsym`$binaryfile ``

but I get a type error

Thanks for the help

Comment: You could add trying 1: which is used for reading in binary files instead of read0 and preparing it using sv and treating it as a text file 
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#read-binary

Comment: `1:` will only work for kdb-protocol binary. OP, your `0:` command is not correct. It should take only two args on the left - the third param is a boolean to which allows for newlines `\n` within strings (a rare case). Which also begs the question - is your file newline separated? Hard to answer your question without seeing the file

Answer (score 0):

```
get hsym`$binaryfile
```

...should work.